# Facebook Registration Tool: how to use in Wordpress?

Tags: facebook, authentication, user-registration, single-sign-on, signup

Facebook provides a Tool to let Facebook users register to third party websites:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/

How to integrate this tool into Wordpress?

I would like to facilitate registration and creation of WP users with this tool.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about an obsolete Facebook feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple Facebook Connect uses this exact registration widget.

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/

Comment: oh hi Otto, you must be the author of the plugin, glad you answered here - so, SFC creates a user in WP... But suppose I use a custom form to register a user (with Gravity forms), can your plugin be appended to the original WP registration form or can I call some function anywhere in a custom theme? Another question, if you don't mind, do Simple Twitter Connect and Simple Google Connect also create users registered in the WP tables? thank you so much

Comment: STC and SGC do not have registration mechanisms at present. SFC-Register replaces the normal WP registration form, but does nothing special with custom registration mechanisms. SFC-Login supports connecting new WP users to FB logins after the fact, they can simply connect their two accounts on their Users->Profile page.

Comment: The link is dead now. Please update or remove this answer.

Comment: SE won't let me remove the answer. However, the question itself is dead as well, since FB have since removed or deprecated their registration widget.

Answer (score 1):

I recently tried my hands on this plugin: http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/ which worked pretty well.

I used that for a while before switching to http://Janrain.com

Anyway, you might want to look into the many other solutions in the plugin store:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/search.php?q=facebook+connect&sort=

Even if you are planning to build something on your own, I'd suggest you take a look at these plugins' code. :)

Good day.

-Sterex

Comment: ah, thanks... since you're a Jainrain user, could you tell me if the plugin actually creates users (that is wordpress users in wpdb, with a display name, registered email and password) or just authorizes a signon with a trusted service (FB, twitter etc). thanks

Comment: It creates a user on WP and validates the user the next time based on email. :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to pay monthly/yearly fees to use janrain service if you get more user registrations.

So i suggest you to try otto's

1. [simple facebook connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-facebook-connect/),
2. [simple twitter connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-twitter-connect/),
3. [simple google connect](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simple-google-connect/).

I've tried many social connect plugins. Otto's plugins are the best i've tried so far.

Because they are updated often. All of them now supports WP 3.3. You can get support from him easily because otto is an active member in wordpress forums as well as here.

Comment: hi there, yeah I thought of those - but do they create a user in the WP tables? also Twitter? (I thought Twitter had some limitation in creating a full registered user, not sure if Twitter passes the Twitter email to WP) thanks